# Invalid API key in Facebook application

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have a simple facebook application with 2 pages - MasterPage.master and Default.aspx (I use ASP .NET). But when I try to run it on Facebook, it returns 500 http code (Invalid API key).

I have checked API key (and Application Secret, too). They are right.

May be, I use them wrong? In my code, The MasterPage.master inherits CanvasFBMLMasterPage and the default inherits CanvasFBMLBasePage. I have a following code on Default.aspx (VB .NET)

```
Imports Facebook
Imports Facebook.WebControls

Partial Class _Default
Inherits CanvasFBMLBasePage
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     MyBase.Load

    MyBase.Api = "my api code"
    MyBase.Secret = "my secret code"
    MyBase.Page_Load(sender, e)


End Sub

End Class
```

Is it true way?
Could you help me? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, when I used Master.RequireLogin = true; (in Page_PreInit) on every page, exept MasterPage. My settings was situated in web.config